# Delphi XML - obtaining a value from parent node

Tags: xml, delphi

I am new to using XML in Delphi, and have used the questions already posted to find out most of what I need to know (thank you!).  However ... I am struggling to obtain a data value from the top of the XML file issued by one of our suppliers.

The top of the XML file is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form billId="1004" penId="ABCDE" appName="Report Sheet" penSerialNo="AJX-AAT-AGK-B4" >
<question id="1" reference="site_name" value="Acme Inc" /></question>
<question id="2" reference="site_address" value="London" /></question>
<question id="3" reference="TQM_job_no" value="AB1234567" /></question>
<question id="4" reference="TQM_site_no" value="XX999" /></question>
```

How can I obtain the **penId** and **penSerialNo** values?

For reference, I am using the code below, obtained from another post on the site, to traverse the XML and obtain the values from the *question* nodes:

```
for i:= 0 to XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
   begin
       Node:= XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[I];
 if Node.NodeName = 'question' then
  begin
   if Node.HasAttribute('value') then
    VALUEvar:= Node.Attributes[value'];
    // do something with VALUEvar which is a string
      end;
end;
end;
```

I would really appreciate any help that could be provided ... thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply change `'question'` to `'form'` and `'value'` to `'penId'`. Have you tried that? Not the most optimal solution, but I wonder if you tried that.

Comment: Hi, yes I did try that, with no success.  I added the line of code:   if Node.NodeName = 'form' then showmessage('Hello World');
but this message never displays, so I am at a loss to understand how I can obtain the attributes values I need>>

Comment: Is it a valid to use `<tag attr="value" /></tag>` ?

Comment: `form` node is the root node. you have to use  code like `xml.documentElement.Attributes['penId']` to get its attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `form` is your root node, you can use something like this:

```
uses
  XMLDoc, XMLIntf;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  XMLDocument: IXMLDocument;
begin
  XMLDocument := LoadXMLDocument('c:\YourFile.xml');
  if XMLDocument.DocumentElement.HasAttribute('penId') then
    ShowMessage(VarToStr(XMLDocument.DocumentElement.Attributes['penId']));
  if XMLDocument.DocumentElement.HasAttribute('penSerialNo') then
    ShowMessage(VarToStr(XMLDocument.DocumentElement.Attributes['penSerialNo']));
end;
```

Anyway, your document is invalid. You cannot use tags enclosed like:

```
<tag attr="value"/></tag>
```

Either use:

```
<tag attr="value"/>
```

or

```
<tag attr="value"></tag>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer re the root node, it's much appreciated, and this works exactly as required.  I am not creating the XML so I have gone back to the supplier about the tags.

Comment: Vendors shipping products that produce Malformed XML,  I wish it were rare, but it ain't.

Comment: I have seen horrors of applications producing XML with vanila strings. Yes its out there. That XML sample has some problems I guess.